# How to migrate from Google Analytics to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

In Google Analytics we can track Google Play campaigns
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns?hl=ru#google-play-campaigns
In fact that this API will be closed soon, how should I migrate tracking to Firebase?

Comment: @mate00 It seems like difference is only about changing SDK in app, but I can't find official documentation about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the only way to migrate is to [setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) Firebase Analytics in your project. Firebase tracks Google Play campaigns the same way as GA, so it will automatically detect and record conversions coming from the campaign. Refer to [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en) link for more information on how conversions are tracked in Firebase.